# Please ensure your device has a proper internet connection

Tags: wifi, communication, bluetooth

I have been using the 1st. Gen Kevo for almost 3 years now and was working perfect until last week that stop working with all of our phones (1 iOS and 2 Android) I tried to reset the lock and from that moment I wasn't be able to pair any of the phones, when running the app after pressing the program button to pair, I always get the message "Please ensure your device has a proper internet connection.". I already tried with WiFi,without WiFi, with Blutooth sharing of course, without it and nothing seems to work, neither with the iOS device or the android device.

Comment: did you do what the message is asking you to do?

Comment: Yes, I did. I Configure Blutooth sharing on the phones, Verify the signal strange and is Excellent. Try it with an Iphone and with 2 Androids, and in every attemp I got the sema result..

Comment: are you able to share internet from one phone to another phone?

Comment: Yes, I can share the internet from one phone to another